# Are Sigils of Elohim "relic" codes tied to a Steam account?

Tags: the-talos-principle

[Sigils of Elohim](http://store.steampowered.com/app/321480/Sigils_of_Elohim/) is a game released as promotional material for [The Talos Principle](http://store.steampowered.com/app/257510/The_Talos_Principle/). By solving enough puzzles you get a "relic" reward for the game. I have no interest in playing through SoE. Can the codes be found online (I found nothing) or are they unique and potentially locked to a Steam account?

[image: Rewarded after solving a first set of puzzles in Sigils of Elohim]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the codes can only be used once and are tied to a Steam account.

[image]